# How do I send a CustomEvent via a Node 16 EventTarget?

Tags: node.js

I am interested in mimicking my client-side code on Node to run unit tests. Node 16 includes with it `EventTarget` but no `CustomEvent`.

How do I replicate `CustomEvent` as is used in the browser?

Specifically, I need to add a `detail` property.

Alternatively, both Node and the browser have `new Event`.  is it possible to add a `data` property to `Event` and that work across both Node and browser?

Answer (score 3):

I had to write a polyfill class

```js
class CustomEvent extends Event { 
  constructor(message, data) {
    super(message, data)
    this.detail = data.detail
  }
}

const et = new EventTarget()
et.addEventListener('message', ev => console.log(ev.detail))
et.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('message', { detail: 'foo' }))
```

And the TypeScript version credit to @Astro Bear
in the comment below

```js
class CustomEvent<T> extends Event {
  detail: T;
  constructor(message: string, data: EventInit & { detail: T }) {
    super(message, data);
    this.detail = data.detail;
  }
}
```

Comment: For typescript users:
`class CustomEvent<T> extends Event {
 detail: T;
 constructor(message: string, data: EventInit & { detail: T }) {
  super(message, data);
  this.detail = data.detail;
 }
}`